# line-height is messed up when using sIFR

Tags: css, wordpress, sifr

When using sIFR on the titles (.content h1.pagetitle) in my WP theme, it somehow messes up the spacing and pushes the title down. The actual flash video is the same size as the font, so I think it has something to do with CSS, though I've tried just about everything I could think of and can't get it lined up properly. Here's a link to the site:

http://seanandpeter.com/

Any help would be absolutely appreciated :)

Sean

Answer (score 1):

The layout issue seems to be caused (and fixed) by playing with your `bottom`:

In `sifr.css`:

```
.sIFR-replaced, .sIFR-ignore {
    visibility: visible !important;
    height:31px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:31px;
}
```

(from `http://seanandpeter.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-sifr/sifr/sifr.css`)

Changing that to `bottom: auto` is a start, but it really looks like the CSS rules are quite poor - unable to cope with multi-line sifr and using a really confusing choice of `position` and offset properties... I'd question whether you're using the best `sifr` plugin available...

Comment: Thanks Searlea,

position:relative;
bottom:31px;

That is actually code I inserted into sifr.css to force it to work. You're right, it doesn't handle multi-line and only works on the front pages (provided the titles are only 1 line). When you look at the individual post pages, it's messed up again (pushed 31px up too high, instead of pushed 31px up to the right location).

It seems this is the only sIFR plugin available for Wordpress at this time. Perhaps I should attempt at embedding sIFR into my WP Theme on my own?